# How do you run a regression when categorical variables may be involved, using R?

Tags: r, logistic, categorical-data, categorical-encoding

I have a data set with several categorical and quantitative variables.  Say A, B, and C are categorical with several levels, X and Y are quantitative.

I know that X ~ A will basically just be a regression using dummy variables, and A ~ X will involve logistic regression.  I believe either `lm()` or `glm()` can handle these.

However, I've run a regression in R on A ~ B, where categorical variables are read as factors, and it tells me

```
using type = "numeric" with a factor response will be ignored‘-’ not meaningful for factors‘^’ not meaningful for factors
```

I read elsewhere that these are all instances of a GLM and I know I've seen the `glm()` function used in R so I figured I would try that instead, and I get

```
‘-’ not meaningful for factors
```

I can see that the formula it's applying involves operations that can't meaningfully be done on factors.  If I set `family=binomial` I get an output, but is that exactly what I want?  I've never worked with a multinomial logisitic model but that seems to be what I'm doing and I haven't come across any resource finding that model using glm--so I'm not sure if I need to start using other functions.  At this point I'm kind of going off of a sequence of guesses and increasingly unsure that even if I silence all the error messages I'll actually be looking at an output that means what I think it means.

Moreover I may want to look at, say, A ~ B + C + B*C + X + Y + X*Y.  If I were to do that, again my question is whether I should be finding a way to get the `glm()` function to make it happen, or should I be researching other functions?

Comment: How many categories does your A variable have? Are they ordered or unordered?

Comment: @IsabellaGhement Three levels, unordered.

Comment: Ok, so you have a multinomial regression model , which you can fit with the function multinom from the nnet package (https://stats.idre.ucla.edu/r/dae/multinomial-logistic-regression/) or with the function vglm from the VGAM package (http://rstudio-pubs-static.s3.amazonaws.com/97847_9864f3e09e844c4d995e1a044f420580.html).